# HTML Relative Path Not Showing Image

Tags: html

I have a URL to this link

```
http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/8/5/0/1/85017748/custom_themes/762476756986669176/files/img/home22.jpg
```

I am trying to use a relative path instead of an actual url. For some reason when I do this

```
<div class="background-image-holder">
     <img alt="image" class="background-image" src="files/img/home22.jpg">
</div>
```

The image doesn't show, but when I use a url it shows just fine. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? I've also tried `../files/img/home22.jpg` and `img/home22.jpg` but neither worked.

Comment: A relative URL has to be relative to some other URL. What is the URL of the page that image is supposed to appear on?

Comment: And if you're not sure what it's relative to, you can debug it easily by checking your `<img>`'s `.src` in your console, this will output the absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you have a problem with your relative path, the easiet solution to fix this, is to **inspect your html code** and see what is the path set after that you can figure out which part of the URL you are missing. We can't really help you with the exact relative path you need, because we don't know which system CMS or Framework you are using ..

To inspect your HTML code, open your website in google chrome or firefox (you can use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) and right click =>  **Inspect Element**